# Problems with formatting ascii art in html

Tags: html, formatting, ascii-art

I need to return the ascii art that is located to the Bootstrap card, I'm using `<pre>` now, but this apparently does not help, here is my html.

```html
<div class="content">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-body justify-content-center">
            <h2 class="card-title">Hello.</h2>
            <pre class="card-text"> ______
&lt; hi &gt;
 ------
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
</pre>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Im using the following css styles:

```css
body {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            font-family: 'Ubuntu', serif;
        }

        * {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        .content {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 2;
            left: 50%;
            top: 50%;
            width: 400px;
            height: 150px;
            text-align: center;
            color: #fff;
            transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        }

        .card {
            box-shadow: 0 10px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
            background-color: #083E55;
            width: auto;
        }
```

Output:

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: That HTML seems to work fine. Presumably you have some CSS that is interfering. Provide a [mcve]. Better yet, use the element inspector in your browser to find out what that CSS is change remove it / stop it being applied / override it.

Comment: Yes, I see, I'll try to do as you said.

Comment: The ascii art is being centered.

Comment: These were just attempts to make everything work, nothing depends on this class, if I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by deleting the style

```css
.content {
  text-align: center;
}
```